# Adapt Ansible-Vault via PHP

Tags: python, php, encryption, ansible, ansible-vault

I wrote a dynamic inventory with PHP and a DB. Now I want include some credentials in it. Typically I use ansible-vault and generate the string, put them into the database and only forward the content to the inventory. But sometimes I've credentials (for example from a customer input), that are stored more or less plain in the database. But I don't want to post them plain to the JSON inventory output.

So, PHP needs to generate the ansible-vault result itself.

I looked into the code of [ansible vault](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/218f5c3648a47cf1b0ca02232c0661219a4f4fb6/lib/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py) and I'm sure, Im nearly finished, but I don't understand how Ansible-Vault is converting the binary into the numbers.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Add header
 * 
 * @param string $ciphertext the encrypted and hexlified data as a byte string
 * @param string $cipher unicode cipher name (for ex, 'AES256')
 * @param string $vaultId unicode vault version (for ex, '1.2'). Optional ('1.1' is default)
 * @return string a byte str that should be dumped into a file.
 */
function vault_format(string $ciphertext, string $cipher = "AES256", string $vaultId = "1.1") :string {
  return "\$ANSIBLE_VAULT;".$vaultId.";".$cipher."\n".$ciphertext;
}

/**
 * Python ansible-vault original
def _create_key_cryptography(b_password, b_salt, key_length, iv_length):
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=2 * key_length + iv_length,
            salt=b_salt,
            iterations=10000,
            backend=CRYPTOGRAPHY_BACKEND)
        b_derivedkey = kdf.derive(b_password)

        return b_derivedkey
 */
function create_key(string $secret, string $salt, int $keyLength, int $iv_length) :string {
  return openssl_pbkdf2($secret, $salt, 2* $keyLength+$iv_length, 10000, 'sha256');
  // return hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $secret, $salt, 10000, 2* $keyLength + $iv_length);
}

/**
def _gen_key_initctr(cls, b_password, b_salt):
    # 16 for AES 128, 32 for AES256
    key_length = 32
  
    if HAS_CRYPTOGRAPHY:
        # AES is a 128-bit block cipher, so IVs and counter nonces are 16 bytes
        iv_length = algorithms.AES.block_size // 8
  
        b_derivedkey = cls._create_key_cryptography(b_password, b_salt, key_length, iv_length)
        b_iv = b_derivedkey[(key_length * 2):(key_length * 2) + iv_length]
    elif HAS_PYCRYPTO:
        # match the size used for counter.new to avoid extra work
        iv_length = 16
  
        b_derivedkey = cls._create_key_pycrypto(b_password, b_salt, key_length, iv_length)
        b_iv = hexlify(b_derivedkey[(key_length * 2):(key_length * 2) + iv_length])
    else:
        raise AnsibleError(NEED_CRYPTO_LIBRARY + '(Detected in initctr)')
  
    b_key1 = b_derivedkey[:key_length]
    b_key2 = b_derivedkey[key_length:(key_length * 2)]
  
    return b_key1, b_key2, b_iv
 */
function generate_key_initctr(string $cipher, string $secret, string $salt) :array {
  $key = array();
  
  $key_length = 32;
  
  // AES
  $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
  $derivedkey = create_key($secret,$salt,$key_length,$iv_length);
  
  $iv = substr($derivedkey,$key_length*2,$iv_length);
  
  $key["key1"] = substr($derivedkey,0,$key_length);
  $key["key2"] = substr($derivedkey, $key_length,$key_length);
  $key["iv"] = $iv;
  return $key;
}

/**
  b_salt = os.urandom(32)
  b_password = secret.bytes
  b_key1, b_key2, b_iv = cls._gen_key_initctr(b_password, b_salt)

  if HAS_CRYPTOGRAPHY:
      b_hmac, b_ciphertext = cls._encrypt_cryptography(b_plaintext, b_key1, b_key2, b_iv)
  elif HAS_PYCRYPTO:
      b_hmac, b_ciphertext = cls._encrypt_pycrypto(b_plaintext, b_key1, b_key2, b_iv)
  else:
      raise AnsibleError(NEED_CRYPTO_LIBRARY + '(Detected in encrypt)')

  b_vaulttext = b'\n'.join([hexlify(b_salt), b_hmac, b_ciphertext])
  # Unnecessary but getting rid of it is a backwards incompatible vault
  # format change
  b_vaulttext = hexlify(b_vaulttext)
  return b_vaulttext
 */
function encrypt(string $cipher, string $plaintext, string $secret) :string {
//  $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
  $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
  
  $key = generate_key_initctr($cipher, $secret, $salt);

  echo "key: ".bin2hex($key["iv"])."\n";
  
  $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $key["iv"]);
  $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $secret, true);
  
  $salt = bin2hex($salt);
  $hmac = bin2hex($hmac);
  $crpt = bin2hex($ciphertext_raw);

  $vault = $salt."\n".$hmac."\n".$crpt;
  $ciphertext = bin2hex( $vault );
  
  return vault_format($ciphertext);
}

/**
def decrypt(cls, b_vaulttext, secret):

    b_ciphertext, b_salt, b_crypted_hmac = parse_vaulttext(b_vaulttext)

    b_password = secret.bytes

    b_key1, b_key2, b_iv = cls._gen_key_initctr(b_password, b_salt)

    if HAS_CRYPTOGRAPHY:
        b_plaintext = cls._decrypt_cryptography(b_ciphertext, b_crypted_hmac, b_key1, b_key2, b_iv)
    elif HAS_PYCRYPTO:
        b_plaintext = cls._decrypt_pycrypto(b_ciphertext, b_crypted_hmac, b_key1, b_key2, b_iv)
    else:
        raise AnsibleError(NEED_CRYPTO_LIBRARY + '(Detected in decrypt)')

    return b_plaintext
 */
function decrypt(string $cipher, string $vault, string $secret) :string {
  $vault_parts = explode("\n",hex2bin($vault));
  $salt = hex2bin($vault_parts[0]);
  $hmac = hex2bin($vault_parts[1]);
  $crpt = hex2bin($vault_parts[2]);
  
  $key = generate_key_initctr($cipher, $secret, $salt);
  
  echo "key: ".bin2hex($key["iv"])."\n";
  
  $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($crpt, $cipher, $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $key["iv"]);
  
  return $plaintext;
}

// --------

// $ciphers = openssl_get_cipher_methods();
// print_r($ciphers);

$ciphers = array();
$ciphers[]="aes-256-cbc";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256";
// $ciphers[]="aes-256-ccm";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-cfb";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-cfb1";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-cfb8";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-ctr";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-ofb";
$ciphers[]="aes-256-xts";

// ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file test.pass 'hello world'
$plaintext = "hello world";
$secret = "my-secret-password";
$encrypted = "646135396134386432636334623638646362366562653535346133643330616263323033616132333164366134393134353061306235326165343863383264390a653536663236643463633032613437363066313565336332616331646364383730333064353966653436386662323734373864333936386332653835656534310a3433353564373736303038346663396536346330303664616139383632313363";

echo "$plaintext\n";
foreach ($ciphers as $cipher) {
  echo "\n\ncipher: $cipher\n";
  
  echo "decrypted:".decrypt($cipher, $encrypted, $secret)."\n";
  echo "encrypted:".encrypt($cipher, $plaintext, $secret)."\n";
}
?>
```

As you can see, I've created first an example and try to decrypt the code.
The output is something like

```
hello world


cipher: aes-256-cbc
key: f5c682ba666e1007a14d6f0ecdc76388
decrypted:
key: 2ed49bd57d0c93f14889a7f7d21a21c0
encrypted:$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
643366363136336363313864386630323566343665326465346637333135646336633339376638383031396234343934356638336564623165343835633238620a303332306430376263343365386533343234373362323638336335326232656665343639383437623066636637356637633766616463303738383863363730370a3364633134303264666231306237353032356435393761313561643733623564


cipher: aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1
key: f5c682ba666e1007a14d6f0ecdc76388
decrypted: <binary-output>
key: ecf4c8215533e8fd672a67314d8c7ed0
encrypted:$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
303433383036656133383832376234353237666332313937323263363966633265643936303535613837353932663661653035396534616463376331356539640a393939643935653163626364653434626266373062656534656335323066343634343266643665326261633134373636316239653561666162366161356536610a6538333536356236643165613462386564363635373464353733376631626565


cipher: aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256
key: f5c682ba666e1007a14d6f0ecdc76388
decrypted: <binary-output>
key: 0981caf5fb38c63791091d10fc7ea5a6
encrypted:$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
323435623935626264623363633434333132333763333162386431386339373365623064393566663262326435363036623461666630623136323832336562620a353531306434346434316435326639343262343362633261363230363661666535363861663039336132373264366336396139363538636138353337663164390a6464306430636434366663316265353536636233663538323862343438373563


cipher: aes-256-cfb
key: f5c682ba666e1007a14d6f0ecdc76388
decrypted: <binary-output>
key: 15eca76feb2bfff3341b683928a84557
encrypted:$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
366634656434663732343761643038393233623736616235336163313161366539353766623637353761366135303031396438623733663862303566623438390a373339613366383539396161383937663838306262333633303765333833623561313132363536616137353664333238643664393833333662303231623363340a34333930313464396133316130346633313531306334
```

So I would expect that the correct algoritm shows me directly in PHP, when it was able to decrypt the string. Also I wrote a small playbook just to test the PHP result.

But when I try it with an example playbook like:

```yaml
- name: My Test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    test: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      3566383238386333633437...24c49c24d60
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test }}"
```

The following error occures:

```
PLAY [My Test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)
    
PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

With `-vvvvvvv` I'm getting

```
Tried to use the vault secret (default) to decrypt (None) but it failed. Error: HMAC verification failed: Signature did not match digest.
```

So, neither decrypting nor encrypting is really working. I'm not really sure, what cipher method is used (that's the reason for the loop over all AES256 cipher). Also is there a pendant for PBKDF2HMAC in PHP (tried `openssl_pbkdf2` and `hash_pbkdf2`, I think, there is also a problem with the correct key? And I've problems to understand the Python code. Can the Python code

```py
b_derivedkey[(key_length * 2):(key_length * 2) + iv_length]
```

be replaced in PHP with?

```php
substr($derivedkey,$key_length * 2, $iv_length);
```

And maybe the last problem is the "unused key1 and key2. The original Python code contains this encrypt:

```py
@staticmethod
def _encrypt_cryptography(b_plaintext, b_key1, b_key2, b_iv):
    cipher = C_Cipher(algorithms.AES(b_key1), modes.CTR(b_iv), CRYPTOGRAPHY_BACKEND)
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    b_ciphertext = encryptor.update(padder.update(b_plaintext) + padder.finalize())
    b_ciphertext += encryptor.finalize()
```

I replaced it with:

```php
openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $key["iv"]);
```

The `Cipher` is unknown to me? key1 is some parts of the generated key from PBKDF2HMAC. That sounds strange to me. What does it mean?

Comment: FWIIW, decrypt seems to be something this person have achieved: https://github.com/daniel-ness/ansible-vault

Comment: You shouldn't store customer values plain in a database. Also, I'm reading it as if you're trying to mimic the ansible-vault internal encryption method. I don't think that's a wise choice, what if Ansible updates this method?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - you're my hero. Thanks. This library is absolutly working in both directions. I checked the code and "only" missed two thinks - used the wrong keys for encrypting and did not understand, what the Padding is doing. Everything else is correct.

Comment: @KevinC - I don't store customer data plain in the database. The problem is - I need to expose that data to an Ansible inventory (as JSON) and that is currently "plain" (so I need to decrypt it from the database and put it into the JSON output). I'd like to avoid that. Because Ansible uses Ansible Vault, this is the only "good" solution - or you need to implement your own decrypting filter in Ansible.

Comment: And - I'm not interested in the internal of Ansible Vault. I need to find a way to generate the code - so I "reverse engineered" it. If Ansible changes the output (like in 1.2 or later in 2.0) then - of course there is another algorithm. But 1.1 will still work till somebody (or me) create a PHP equivalent.

Comment: Also - one funny thing. I tried the playbook within my playbooks directory with a ansible.cfg configured inventory file. Because for tests I used a different vault and then (even with a correct content) the playbook here fails because the vault password in the inventory differ from the vault password in the example. Using vault-id would help...haha